# How to add facial recognition based login in ubuntu/linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have written a code (in python) to detect my face. Now I want to add this feature for login in my Ubuntu system. I searched over internet but cannot find suitable answers.

I want to display an option/icon to select facial recognition and on clicking that, my facial recognition code starts running in background. How I can achieve it? Please explain exactly where I need to make changes in ubuntu system for enabling and using such option?

Comment: X is a little bit complex, we have around 5 programs interacting while we get a login. One of them is the tool which puts the "login/password" box. It is started by the "x display manager", their name ends with "dm", light "xdm", "mdm" and so on. The display manager has a configuration, you need to switch in its config into your face recognization tool.

Comment: I think your thing is interesting, I think I could help more, but not in the SO framework. Come into the chat ( https://chat.stackoverflow.com )

Comment: @peterh are you available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use Linux-PAM to allow you to Su/Sudo using facial recognition. I have done this with python + a bash script here: https://github.com/lambrou/susentry
I have taken part of my README and will explain it to you with the context of your question.

The first thing you will need to do is make a bash script that calls your python script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# You must change the value /path/to/susentry.py to the path of your
# python file.
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +local:
python3 /path/to/susentry.py -l # run the python script for facial recognition
exit_status=$? # This grabs the exit status of the python script we just ran
if [ "${exit_status}" -ne 0 ]; # checks to see if exit status is anything other than 0
then
    echo "exit ${exit_status}"
    exit 1 # exit status 1 on python script fail (exit 1)
fi
echo "EXIT 0"
exit 0 # exit 0 if we get to this line
```

What this script does is sets the display to your display, as the PAM module will be calling the script from a different userspace we will need to tell it where your display is, and what xhost you are using. Then, it grabs the exit status of your python script (make sure on facial recognition fail it exits 1, pass it exits 0) and passes it to PAM to let it know whether or not the script passed or failed.
Find this line:

python3 /path/to/susentry.py -l

And change /path/to/susentry.py to the full path of your python script. Then, place this file in /usr/local/bin folder.

Next, we modify the PAM common-auth file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

Find this line in your common-auth file:

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore]     pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

This line calls the module that asks the user for a password. If the module returns success (password correct), it skips the next line (success=1 means skip one line). The goal is to skip the following line if authentication is successful:

```
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
```

As this line denies the user access to privileges.
So, if you want to use su/sudo, but instead of entering your password you use facial comparison, put this *above* the line above:

```
auth [success=2 default=ignore]     pam_exec.so debug log=/path/to/pamlogs.txt /usr/local/bin/susentry
```

Make sure you change /path/to/pamlogs.txt to where you want the PAM output to be saved. (This ouput is error output and stdin output from your PAM, your bash script, and your python script)
Lets break this down.

`auth [success=2 default=ignore]`

Means "If this program returns success (exit 0), then skip the next 2 lines. (Password prompt line, authentication fail line)

`pam_exec.so debug log=/path/to/pamlogs.txt`

This part says "use pam_exec to execute the bash script, and send all the error logs/stdin logs to /path/to/pamlogs.txt

`/usr/local/bin/susentry`

This part is the location of the bash script. This is what PAM exec runs and waits for an exit code for.

**If the facial recognition script fails it should fall back to asking for a password.
Please note that you need to be careful when editing /etc/pam.d/common-auth as you can break your sudo. You may want to open a new terminal with root privileges while you mess with this stuff so you can revert back the changes.**

Comment: so how does PAM and bash script is passing information with each other?   specifically, how does PAM know the location of bash script and also how bash script is passing exit status of python script to PAM?

Comment: @abhi I edited the answer to answer your questions. Namely by adding more comments to the bash script and breaking down the line we add to PAM. Let me know if you need me to explain anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just I need to know two more things. 1. Do I need to use `sys.exit(0)` and `sys.exit(1)` on success and failure from my python script? 2. On unsuccessful face detection, I want to use password-based authentication. So some kind of `if else` statement or `loop` is required which asks for a password from the user. How I can do it here?

Comment: Yes, you need to use sys.exit(1) or 0 as this tells the bash script how the python script exited. The bash script exits the same way, and sends the exit code to PAM.
You do not need an if statement or loop, the PAM modules run in a loop - remember how when you enter your password, you get multiple attempts?
As long as you put the line
`auth [success=2 default=ignore]     pam_exec.so debug log=/path/to/pamlogs.txt /usr/local/bin/susentry` above the line that is already there, it will run exactly how you want it. (It will fall back to password auth if facial recognition fails)

Comment: After system bootup, in the login window, I have obtained the following error using above-mentioned shell script: **xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"
: cannot connect to X server :0.0**. After the login using password, everything worked perfect (in the terminal, software store, etc.). How to remove this error after system boots up and first login screen is displayed?

Comment: Are you using susentry.py, or your own script? If you are using susentry.py, do you have verbose set to True or False?
If you are using your own, are you having any GUI windows pop up in your script?

Comment: I am using the same script file you have provided with the only change to the python file path. I have not made any change to the verbose setting. What should I do next?